# Typescript Pass Inline Void Function Error

Tags: typescript, babylonjs

I have got a question about TypeScript and Functions as Arguments. I had the problem with BabylonJS but I think, it is about all TypeScript. I am storing the render function in my class:

```
this._renderloop = newScene.render; // render(): void; is a function of BabylonJS.Scene class
```

and call the BabylonJS renderLoop via

```
this._webglEngine.runRenderLoop(this._renderloop);
```

This is giving me errors about some properties (e.g. _activeParticles) of Scene not being initialized.

But when I am setting the renderloop via:

```
this._renderloop = () => newScene.render();
this._webglEngine.runRenderLoop(this.renderloop);
```

everything is working fine.

What is the problem with the first call? Wouldn't the second be more performant, because I skips one function call?

(BabylonJS Docs can be found here: https://doc.babylonjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this._webglEngine.runRenderLoop(newScene.render)
```

The `this` inside [scene.render](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/037d7a85efe6626e082fa9438412e835008f8234/src/babylon.scene.ts#L4518) will be undefined. The easiest way to fix it is to wrap it in a function like your second example.

This is because of the way javascript handles `this`. There's a nice guide on using [`this` in the Typescript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript).

Comment: I am still confused about the different thises:

Why is `this`undefined inside `scene.render` in `this._webglEngine.runRenderLoop(newScene.render);` but not in `this._webglEngine.runRenderLoop(() => newScene.render());`?